# String modifications in SQL Server don't get saved until query completes

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    pp.Product_ID, p.LabelEN, p.ID, pc.Comments, pc.lang 
INTO 
    #TEMPTBL
FROM
    #Product_Comments pc 
JOIN
    Product_Property vp ON pp.Product_ID=pc.Product_ID
JOIN 
    Product p ON p.ID = pp.Product_ID
JOIN 
    #prod pdom ON pdom.ID = p.ID
JOIN 
    Property p ON p.ID = pp.Property_ID
JOIN 
    IncludedPropertyCategory ipc ON p.ID = ipc.Property_ID
WHERE 
    pc.lang = 'EN' 

UPDATE pc
SET pc.Comments = p.LabelEN+', '+p.Comments
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM #TEMPTBL) AS p 
JOIN #Product_Comments AS pc ON p.Product_ID = pc.Product_ID AND p.lang = pc.lang
```

I have these queries shown above and the `UPDATE` appends every feature (property) to the comment column; however, the problem is that when a product has several features it only saves the last one. For example, let's say that the product has the following feature: lightweight, electric, premium and new, then only new would get prepended.

I want all features to be prepended to the string.

I get something like: "new are the features this product has".

When I want: "lightweight, electric, premium and new are the features this product has".

Comment: This is another reason why the untrustworthy syntax `SET @Variable = COALESCE(@Variable,'') + SomeColumn FROM dbo.SomeTable;` teaches bad habits too. `SET` isn't iterative, so the above is only going to work for the *last* row, it's won't aggregate the string. If you want to aggregate strings look at `STRING_AGG` or the old `FOR XML PATH` method,

Comment: STRING_AGG won't work, because I need to append to an existing string.

Comment: Why won't it? What's wrong with `'Some String' + STRING_AGG(...)`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try it.

```
UPDATE pc
SET pc.Comments = p.NewComment
FROM (
    SELECT TMP1.Product_Id, TMP1.lang, STRING_AGG(NewCommentTmp, ',') AS NewComment
    FROM (
        SELECT *, p.LabelEN + ', ' + p.Comment AS NewCommentTmp
        FROM #TEMPTBL
    ) TMP1
) AS p
JOIN #Product_Comments AS pc ON p.Product_ID = pc.Product_ID AND p.lang = pc.lang;
```

Comment: Remarkably, it's similar to the one I came up with, except I also put a join statement inside the inner select. I think you need to change the inner script so that it returns only 1 row. Otherwise, it won't work. I think I faced that issue when I wrote it.